# jQuery exception handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception

Is there any way I could catch any uncaught exception in javascript? I mean, all my "dangerous" code are in try-catch blocks. But what about exceptions that I don't handle explicitly? I'm using jQuery, my main javascript file starts with :

`$(document).ready(function(){})`

here I bind some events to some DOM elements. I can use try-catch blocks here, but they will catch exceptions that occur during the event binding procedure, not during the event handling. But if I used try-catch blocks in every event handling functions it would be ugly.

How should I catch exceptions that don't occur in my explicit try-catch blocks? (I don't want to write a general handler function, I just want to send the problem to my server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could write a function that would wrap your real handlers in a try/catch

```
function tc(func, msg) {
  msg = msg || "Handler exception";
  return function(e) {
    try {
      return func(e);
    }
    catch (exc) {
      $.post( /* send exception to server? */ );
      throw exc; // let nature take its course
    }
  };
}
```

(Might want to get fancier with argument handling etc.) Then when you bind handlers you'd do:

```
$('#whatever').click(tc(function(e) {
  // your handler function
}, "This is the message sent to the server when this handler fails"));
```

Also, if you want to make sure "`this`" in the handler behaves as before, you can do `func.apply($(this), e)` instead of just `func(e)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror) event handler, it's not supported in Opera though and [it may not fire in certain situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915812/window-onerror-does-not-work) (thanks @Josh).

It's not really wise to do this, however, it will make bug finding a nightmare for a start.  It's generally best to make sure your code is error free in the first place :-) You certainly shouldn't need to use `try... catch` statements very often in JavaScript and you definitely shouldn't be using empty `catch` blocks.

> *I can use try-catch blocks here, but they will caught exceptions that occured during the event binding procedure, not during the event handling.*

You can also add try/catch blocks to inner scopes:

```
// Outer
try { 
    $(document).ready(function(){})
}
catch (e) {
    /* Error handling */
}

// Inner
$(document).ready(function(){
    try { /* ... */ } catch (e) { /* Error handling */ }
});
```

Comment: This event may or may not fire, depending on the user agent configuration.

Comment: More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915812/window-onerror-does-not-work

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
    function func_madness() {
        throw("This function is throwing exceptions, because \n" +
        "it can not throw polar bears and whales.\n");
    } // func_madness

    window.onload = function () {
        try {
            func_madness();
        } catch (err) {
            document.write("Caught it!\n<br/>\n" + err);
        } // catch
    } // window.onload
```