# javascript runtime error not handled even with code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this code in my masterpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function silentErrorHandler() { return true; }
    window.onerror = silentErrorHandler;
alert("handled");
</script>
```

But I am still getting this error:
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'scrollLeft': object is null or undefined

How can I fully suppress these errors without having to set the disable script debugging in ie?

I would fix the error but I have spent too long looking at this issue and no one has commented on my other post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915208/jscript-runtime-error-on-callback-using-updatepanel

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/WinPlan.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="Scheduler.aspx.vb" Inherits="Scheduler" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="act" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DayPilot" Namespace="DayPilot.Web.Ui" TagPrefix="DayPilot" %>
<asp:Content ID="PageHeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="page_header_content" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlSearchBar" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="searchBar">
                <table id="userSearchBar">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From: " Font-Bold="true" Width="50"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" Width="80"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCalendarFrom" runat="server" Width="18" ImageUrl="~/Images/SmallCalendar.gif" />
                            <act:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderFrom" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                Enabled="true" PopupButtonID="imgCalendarFrom" TargetControlID="txtFromDate">
                            </act:CalendarExtender>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:Label ID="l3" Text="" runat="server" Width="20"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="To: " Font-Bold="true" Width="30"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" Width="80"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCalendarTo" runat="server" Width="18" ImageUrl="~/Images/SmallCalendar.gif" />
                            <act:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderTo" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                Enabled="true" PopupButtonID="imgCalendarTo" TargetControlID="txtToDate">
                            </act:CalendarExtender>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:Label ID="l4" Text="" runat="server" Width="20"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSearchSchedules" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="60px" BorderStyle="None"
                                Height="22px" ForeColor="White" CssClass="btn" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <asp:Label ID="L5" Text="" runat="server" Width="20"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="middle">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnUsers" runat="server" Text="Users" Width="60px" BorderStyle="None"
                                Height="22px" ForeColor="White" CssClass="btn" OnClientClick="editUsers();" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle">
                            <asp:Label ID="L6" Text="" runat="server" Width="20"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="bottom">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBusinessHours" runat="server" Text=" Show Business Hours Only"
                                Height="22px" BorderColor="Transparent" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Black" AutoPostBack="true" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="40px">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table id="adminSearchBar" runat="server">
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="main_content" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="dp">
                <DayPilot:DayPilotScheduler ID="DayPilotScheduler1" runat="server" CellGroupBy="Day"
                    DataStartField="StartDate" DataEndField="EndDate" ScrollLabelsVisible="true"
                    DataTextField="CustomerName" DataValueField="Workcard" DataResourceField="EmployeeCode"
                    CellDuration="60" CellWidth="50" ViewType="Resources" Width="100%" Heigth="100%"
                    RowMinHeight="30" RowHeaderWidth="150" HeigthSpec="Max" HeaderFontSize="10pt"
                    HeaderWidth="150px" HeaderHeight="20" EventFontSize="8pt" EventMoveHandling="CallBack"
                    TimeFormat="Clock12Hours" DurationBarVisible="false" BusinessBeginsHour="8" BusinessEndsHour="18"
                    ClientObjectName="dps" EventClickHandling="JavaScript" EventClickJavaScript="editEvent(e.value());"
                    OnCommand="DayPilotScheduler1_Command" EventCorners="Regular" RowMarginBottom="5"
                    ContextMenuID="DayPilotContextMenu" TreeIndent="15" TreeImageNoChildren="images/tree_nochildren.png"
                    TreeImageCollapse="images/tree_collapse.png" TreeImageExpand="images/tree_expand.png"
                    CssClassPrefix="scheduler_" EventBackColor="" EventFontFamily="" HourNameBackColor=""
                    HourFontFamily="" HourFontSize="" HeaderFontFamily="" HourBorderColor="" BackColor="#ececfe"
                    NonBusinessBackColor="White" CellBorderColor="Silver" OnBeforeResHeaderRender="DayPilotScheduler1_BeforeResHeaderRender"
                    AutoRefreshEnabled="true" AutoRefreshInterval="10" HeightSpec="Max" Height="630">
                </DayPilot:DayPilotScheduler>
                <DayPilot:DayPilotMenu ID="DayPilotContextMenu" runat="server" CssClassPrefix="menu_">
                    <DayPilot:MenuItem Action="Javascript" JavaScript="redirect()" Command="Details"
                        Text="View Job Creator" />
                </DayPilot:DayPilotMenu>
                <asp:UpdateProgress DynamicLayout="false" DisplayAfter="1" ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server">
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <div class="Progress">
                            <img src="./images/ajax-loader.gif" />
                            Loading ...
                        </div>
                    </ProgressTemplate>
                </asp:UpdateProgress>
                <act:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender ID="AlwaysVisible" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdateProgress2"
                    HorizontalSide="Center" VerticalSide="Middle" HorizontalOffset="0">
                </act:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You never posted any code (as requested) on the other question, so nobody could help.  Those errors can be caused by all sorts of things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.onerror does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915812/window-onerror-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft documentation:

> The onerror event fires for run-time errors, but not for compilation errors. In addition, error dialog boxes raised by script debuggers are not suppressed by returning true. To turn off script debuggers, disable script debugging in Internet Explorer by choosing Internet Options from the Tools menu. Click the Advanced tab and select the appropriate check box(es).

On the bright side, most ordinary IE users (or users of any other browser, for that matter) don't have script debugging enabled.

Comment: I need to be able to suppress the errors without changing settings in ie. The error seems to be coming from the daypilot control when it is surrounded by an updatepanel which i need. when i check the control properties in jscript the scrollleft, scrolltop properties are set to 0.

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about those controls.  If you can't have the error popups, the right solution is to fix those errors. Maybe the IE8/9 developer tools can help find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the JavaScript code is generated by server side because your ASP.net code doesn't contain any JavaScript code. As a result, it's difficult to tell where goes wrong.

Comment: yes it is generated server side. when i looked at the daypilot scheduler properties through js i found that the scrollLeft and scrollTop propertied were set to 0 even though the error says they are null or undefined... im lost