# IE showing JS Error Dialog even though window.onerror returning true

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

I have some JS that registers a handler for window.onerror:

```
window.onerror=function(){
  //code removed
  return true;
}
```

But when I throw an exception on the page, I still get the error dialog popping up in IE displaying my error message and line number and asking me if I want to debug.  I realize that this is because I have VS installed on my machine, but is there any way to prevent this dialog from showing short of checking the "do not display this message..." option?  Some of my users will have VS installed on their machine and I'd rather not have them see this message in my app.

Thanks,

D

Comment: You can check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915812/window-onerror-does-not-work

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to figure out if there's something I can do in my code to prevent it.  Sort of like the opposite of the `debugger` statement to say "don't attach a debugger here."